# Convert or Extract Year, Month and Date from a string in PHP

Tags: php, php-5.3

All,

I have the following string:

```
$dateTime = '2013-09-15T00:00:00.000Z';
```

Is there a function to extract Year, Month and Date from the above string, so the result looks like the following:

```
$yearMonthDate = '2013-09-15';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert your datetime to a timestamp using `strtotime()` and then convert it back into a formatted date using this kind of syntax:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($myOriginalDate))
```

Comment: Thanks..How do I convert that string to a timestamp? Isn't it already in timestamp format?

Comment: @Jake no, timestamps are integers. What you have is a date/time in ISO 8601 format.

Comment: Excellent Solution. Thanks Doug and Brian for the clarification.

Comment: By timestamp, I mean a unix timestamp, as in the number of seconds since 1st Jan 1970. Have a look at the php strtotime documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

[substr](http://php.net/substr) or  [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) or [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)+[date](http://php.net/date)

Answer (score 0):

Since the first string is actually a [standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), you can just use substr:

```
$yearMonthDate = substr($dateTime, 0, 10);
```

However, that would be kind of a hack and would obviously break if the format of `$dateTime` were to change. So, you might want to look into the PHP `DateTime` class instead.